# Error: "attempted index of non-table" when trying to assign a new property to an object

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make a mod to a game (Project Zomboid). An object is passed to an event and I'm trying to add a new property to it, like this:

`theObject.newProperty = 100`

but an error is thrown: `attempted index of non-table`. I know that `theObject` is an object, I can access it's methods. I'm a beginner in Lua, but from what I read all objects are tables, so this error doesn't make sense to me. What can be happening here?

Comment: What happens when you `print( type( theObject ) )`?  I'm guessing it's userdata...

Comment: yes it is userdata. So what does it mean?

Comment: It means that `theObject` is not a table. You can access its methods, most probably, because they are provided by `theObject`'s metatable.

Comment: yea, it's essentially a blackbox written in C/C++ (or whatever language the app is).  You'd need to modify the source, then recompile, to have any effect on it.  or ask the dev's to include that ability in the next release.

Comment: Thank you guys. @Doyousketch2 If you would like the reputation points please create an answer that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you print( type( theObject ) )? I'm guessing it's userdata...

> yes it is userdata. So what does it mean? – Eggon

yea, it's essentially a blackbox written in C/C++ (or whatever language the app is).

You'd need to modify the source, then recompile, to have any effect on it.  Or ask the dev's to include that ability in the next release.